# cgroups error 50016

Tags: cgroup

creating a question [from the forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1814229) so i can answer it here and leave for others as it took me ages to debug this one

hi,

i would like to test the following:
the process bzip2 for user testuser goes into the group cpuhungry
the group is only allowed to use core 1, not core 0.

/etc/cgrules.conf

```
testuser:bzip2   cpuset   cpuhungry/;
```

/etc/cgconfig.conf

```
mount {
  cpuset = /mnt/cgroups/cpuset;
}

group cpuhungry {
  cpuset {
      cpuset.cpus = 1
  }
}
```

ive tried the init skript some times, but i guess it is broken.
looks like you need to run

`cgconfigparser -l /etc/cgconfig.conf`
to setup the mounts in the first place, the init script misses this step.

starting the daemon via:
`sudo cgrulesengd -d`
results in:

```
CGroup Rules Engine Daemon log started
Current time: Fri Jul 29 11:32:53 2011

Opened log file: -, log facility: 0, log level: 7
Proceeding with PID 9527
Rule: testuser:bzip2
  UID: 1000
  GID: N/A
  DEST: cpuhungry/
  CONTROLLERS:
    cpuset

Started the CGroup Rules Engine Daemon.
.
.
.
Cgroup change for PID: 9528, UID: 1000, GID: 1000, PROCNAME: /bin/bzip2 FAILED! (Error Code: 50016)
GID Event: PID = 1950, tGID = 1950, rGID = 0, eGID = 122
```

the error code 50016 is of course not documented nor does something pop up in a google search.

any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the `cpuset.mems` resources is not populated to fix this simply populate it with one of the following

run

`echo 0 > /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuhungry/cpuset.mems`

or

`cgset -r cpuset.mems=0 cpuhungry`

or update     /etc/cgconfig.conf

```
mount {
  cpuset = /mnt/cgroups/cpuset;
}

group cpuhungry {
  cpuset {
      cpuset.cpus = 1
      cpuset.mems = 0
  }
}
```

[also see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37533173/getting-cgroup-change-of-group-failed-when-trying-to-add-process-to-cgroup)